# Bash read array from an external file

Tags: bash

I have setup a Bash menu script that also requires user input.
These inputs are wrote (appended to) a text file named var.txt like so:

```
input[0]='192.0.0.1'
input[1]='username'
input[2]='example.com'
input[3]='/home/newuser'
```

Now what I am trying to accomplish is to be able to read from var.txt from a script kinda like this:

```
useradd var.txt/${input[1]}
```

now I know that wont work just using it for an example.

Thanks in Advance,
Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate your variable extraction in a function and take advantage of the fact that `declare` creates local variables when used inside a function. This technique reads the file each time the function is called.

```
readvar () {
    # call like this: readvar filename variable
    while read -r line
    do
        # you could do some validation here
        declare "$line"
    done < "$1"
    echo ${!2}
}
```

Given a file called "data" containing:

```
input[0]='192.0.0.1'
input[1]='username'
input[2]='example.com'
input[3]='/home/newuser'
foo=bar
bar=baz
```

You could do:

```
$ a=$(readvar data input[1])
$ echo "$a"
username
$ readvar data foo
bar
```

This will read an array and rename it:

```
readarray () {
    # call like this: readarray filename arrayname newname
    # newname may be omitted and will default to the existing name
    while read -r line
    do
        declare "$line"
    done < "$1"
    local d=$(declare -p $2)
    echo ${d/#declare -a $2/declare -a ${3:-$2}};
}
```

Examples:

```
$ eval $(readarray data input output)
$ echo ${output[2]}
example.com
$ echo ${output[0]}
192.0.0.1
$ eval $(readarray data input)
$ echo ${input[3]}
/home/newuser
```

Doing it this way, you would only need to make one call to the function and the entire array would be available instead of having to make individual queries.

Comment: Wow! Thanks I have not had a chance to test these yet, but I am sure this will most definitely work for what I am trying to accomplish. Automated server installation and configuration-a must have in reproducing systems! Should have time over the weekend to test these out. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @jmituzas: Note that in Bash 4 there is a builtin called "readarray" which is a synonym for "mapfile". These commands read lines from a file into an array. They don't do the variable setting as shown in my answer, but you could probably blend the the techniques.

Comment: Awesome! All of these versions helped me out in so many ways.

Answer (score 16):

Use [bash's `readarray` statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray). (It's the only way I can find to put spaces in array elements dynamically.) You'll need your `var.txt` file to simply contain the elements of the array, one on each line, not contain assignment statements.

```
readarray -t input < var.txt
```

For more info, try `help readarray` (which will then tell you to try `help mapfile`).

Here's my test for it:

```
echo -e "a\nb c\nd" > var.txt
readarray input < var.txt 
for item in "${input[@]}"; do echo $item; done
```

prints:

```
a
b c
d
```

**Note**: doing `cat var.txt | readarray -t input` doesn't work. I think it's because the `input` variable is scoped out of reach.

Comment: Normally in a bash array spaces are considered separators and become distinct array elements. So the behavior when reading a file is not consistent?

Comment: In my previous comment I'm referring to the compound assignment name=(value1 value2 … )

Answer (score 8):

If the whole `var.txt` file contains only Bash-compatible variable assignments as you indicated, you might just be able to [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) it, to make those variables available in a new Bash script:

```
source var.txt

useradd ${input[1]}
```

This, however, will overwrite any existing variable with the same name. [Command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) can be used to avoid this, by selecting specific variables:

```
input[1]="$(grep '^input\[1\]=' var.txt | sed "s|[^=]*='\(.*\)'|\1|")"
```

It allows for renaming variables, although you will have to do this for each variable of interest. It essentially extracts the value of the variable from the `var.txt` file and assigns it to a new variable. See the [grep manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and the [sed info page](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) for more information on their use.

[Process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) may allow for simpler expressions:

```
source <(grep '^input\[[0-9]*\]=' var.txt)

useradd ${input[1]}
```

This would allow you to import only definitions of interest, although you have to watch for unwanted variable overwrites.

Comment: Awesome will try when I return home in about an hr. Yes it does only contain Bash-compatible variable assignments.

Comment: Thanks for those links, lots of really useful info there.