# Variable Redirect in bash vs. ksh

Tags: bash, variables, reference, ksh

I found this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

readvar () {
    while read -r line
    do
            declare "$line"
    done < "$1"
    echo ${!2}
}
```

Over here:
[Bash Read Array from External File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685323/bash-read-array-from-external-file)

I have a file called test.txt:

```
_127_0_0_1=kees
```

If I do in bash:

```
readvar ./test.txt _127_0_0_1
```

I get the output:

```
kees
```

However if I do the same thing in ksh, 
(Declare doesn't work in ksh so I replaced it with typeset.)
:

```
#!/bin/ksh

readvar () {
    while read -r line
    do
            typeset "$line"
    done < "$1"
    echo ${!2}
}

readvar ./test.txt _127_0_0_1
```

I get the output:

```
$ ./test.sh

./test.sh: syntax error at line 8: `2' unexpected Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is that ? And how can I make it work in ksh?
(ksh93 for that matter)

Comment: `$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's `man ksh`:

```
   ${!vname}
          Expands to the name of the variable referred to by vname.  
          This will be vname except when vname is a name reference.
```

As you can see, this is completely different from what bash does.

For indirection in `ksh`, you can use `nameref` (an alias for `typeset -n`):

```
foo() {
  bar=42
  nameref indirect="$1"
  echo "$indirect"
}
foo bar
```

Comment: `#!/bin/ksh

foo() {
 while read -r line
    do
            typeset "$line"
    done < "$1"

  nameref indirect="$2"
  echo "$indirect"
}

foo ./test.txt _127_0_0_1`  input test.txt:  `_127_0_0_1=kees` output: `kees`

Comment: @azbc: Another convenient function of setting `nameref` in `ksh` is you can also change it's value (eg. `eval "${!indirect}=foobar"`) ... `echo "${!indirect}=${indirect}" `